# Efficient way to calculate part of a multivariate normal density

Tags: julia

I am interested in calculating quantity:

[image: (\boldsymbol{x_i}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^T \boldsymbol{W} (\boldsymbol{x_i}-\boldsymbol{\mu})]

where **x_i** is a 1xD vector (one out of my N data of dimension D), **μ** is a DxK matrix and **W** is a list of K DxD matrices.

This should result in a 1XK vector. I try it for all N and K in the following way that works:

```
res = zeros(N,K);
for i in 1:N
    for k in 1:K
        res[i,k] = (x_matrix[i,:]-mus_matrix[:,k])'*
                   w_matrix[k]*(x_matrix[i,:]-mus_matrix[:,k])
```

If I try to vectorize it, using the following:

```
 res = zeros(N,K);
for i in 1:N
        res[i,:] = (x_matrix[i,:].-mus_matrix)'.*w_matrix.*(x_matrix[i,:].-mus_matrix)
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("arrays could not be broadcast to a common size")
Stacktrace:
 [1] _bcs1(::Base.OneTo{Int64}, ::Base.OneTo{Int64}) at ./broadcast.jl:70
 [2] _bcs at ./broadcast.jl:63 [inlined]
 [3] broadcast_shape(::Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64},Base.OneTo{Int64}}, ::Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, ::Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64},Base.OneTo{Int64}}, ::Vararg{Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64},Base.OneTo{Int64}},N} where N) at ./broadcast.jl:57 (repeats 3 times)
 [4] broadcast_indices(::Array{Float64,2}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at ./broadcast.jl:53
 [5] broadcast_c(::Function, ::Type{Array}, ::Array{Float64,2}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at ./broadcast.jl:311
 [6] broadcast(::Function, ::Array{Float64,2}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at ./broadcast.jl:434
```

Here is an example:

```
julia> N = 5
5

julia> D=2
2

julia> K = 4
4

julia> W=[]
0-element Array{Any,1}

julia> x = rand(N,D)
5×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.576477  0.9575  
 0.184454  0.660436
 0.470267  0.729649
 0.648879  0.782561
 0.626453  0.111332

julia> mu = rand(K,D)
4×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.989281  0.00126782
 0.659106  0.66136   
 0.50843   0.289442  
 0.327962  0.523229  

julia> for i in 1:K
           push!(W,rand(D,D))
       end
```

And then run

```
julia> (x_matrix[i,:]-mus_matrix[:,k])'*
                               w_matrix[k]*(x_matrix[i,:]-mus_matrix[:,k])
34649.850360744866
```

But with the second code

```
julia> (x_matrix[i,:].-mus_matrix)'.*w_matrix.*(x_matrix[i,:].-mus_matrix)
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("arrays could not be broadcast to a common size")
Stacktrace:
 [1] _bcs1(::Base.OneTo{Int64}, ::Base.OneTo{Int64}) at ./broadcast.jl:70
 [2] _bcs at ./broadcast.jl:63 [inlined]
 [3] broadcast_shape(::Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64},Base.OneTo{Int64}}, ::Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, ::Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64},Base.OneTo{Int64}}, ::Vararg{Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64},Base.OneTo{Int64}},N} where N) at ./broadcast.jl:57 (repeats 3 times)
 [4] broadcast_indices(::Array{Float64,2}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at ./broadcast.jl:53
 [5] broadcast_c(::Function, ::Type{Array}, ::Array{Float64,2}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at ./broadcast.jl:311
 [6] broadcast(::Function, ::Array{Float64,2}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at ./broadcast.jl:434
```

Comment: There are several issues with your second and possibly with the first code. You are vectorizing the inner-loop, but inner-loop is still there. res[i,k] is a `Number` but right hand side is a vector. 

There are several ways to define a list of matrices for `W`. How did you define it? Can you give an output of `size(W)`?

It would be great if you could give some sample matrices for `x_matrix`, `mu_matrix` and especially `W`.

Yes, there are probably some ways to get rid of the outer-loop.

Another issue is that you cannot take a difference of vector of size D from a matrix of size(K,D).

Comment: Specifically, `x_matrix[i,:]-mus_matrix` gives a `DimensionMismatch`. I am also not sure that elementary-wise multiplication with `w_matrix` will give you the result you want.

Comment: You are right, I had some problems with my second code, but that was due to copy paste, I just corrected it! Still get an error, a different one this time. I added an example in the problem above, hope that helps a bit! Maybe has to do with the way I am defining the list W?

Comment: The dimension in the example you gave seems not compatible with what is described in the question. Which one is correct? Also how do you define `x_i - u`? What I understand from the dimesions you gave it should add `x_i` to each column of `-u`. Then the dimension is `D*K` and the resulting dimension is `K*K` not `1*K`? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL/DR: optimized variant below, but Einsum looks nicer, IMHO.

---

Looks like a case for using [Einstein summation notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation).  In Julia, [`Einsum.jl`](https://github.com/ahwillia/Einsum.jl) can do this:

```
julia> N = 5
5

julia> D = 3
3

julia> K = 10
10

julia> x = rand(N, D)
5×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.587436  0.210529  0.261725
 0.527269  0.457477  0.482939
 0.52726   0.411209  0.138872
 0.89107   0.464789  0.758392
 0.885267  0.931014  0.672959

julia> μ = rand(D, K)
3×10 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.280792   0.265066   0.81437   0.503377  0.0717916  …  0.275872  0.609961   0.0820088  0.0042564
 0.0177643  0.0959438  0.563948  0.332433  0.088527      0.691971  0.0296638  0.604488   0.956057 
 0.668128   0.444816   0.74203   0.518232  0.48689       0.465067  0.117469   0.729514   0.109973 

julia> W = rand(K, D, D)
10×3×3 Array{Float64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 0.320861   0.662103  0.219234
 0.780944   0.769377  0.566203
 0.466207   0.428527  0.330901
 0.15534    0.035435  0.346737
 0.810676   0.328116  0.469505
 0.676575   0.668204  0.285334
 0.455551   0.211295  0.85295 
 0.229995   0.741487  0.783361
 0.0937583  0.401419  0.47032 
 0.956335   0.434213  0.967791

[:, :, 2] =
 0.275903   0.130298   0.184485
 0.941648   0.940107   0.439454
 0.425292   0.252654   0.797115
 0.0203406  0.594075   0.484809
 0.164309   0.941597   0.455314
 0.73628    0.109502   0.920664
 0.906305   0.177235   0.540193
 0.360038   0.0486971  0.20626 
 0.914357   0.699901   0.295872
 0.284143   0.659117   0.291479

[:, :, 3] =
 0.138311   0.921371  0.353719
 0.345247   0.70865   0.246736
 0.361364   0.636543  0.343837
 0.752149   0.581561  0.346399
 0.705888   0.24765   0.703952
 0.992327   0.369668  0.109407
 0.341624   0.223715  0.970667
 0.762169   0.94248   0.917569
 0.0367128  0.589345  0.121106
 0.826602   0.692111  0.229499

julia> using Einsum

julia> @einsum r[n,k] := (x[n,i] - μ[i,k]) * W[k,i,j] * (x[n,j] - μ[j,k])

julia> r
5×10 Array{Float64,2}:
  0.0176889  0.087092   0.522184    0.0417967   …  -0.0430999   0.041266   -0.0596579  0.432076
  0.0521066  0.364059   0.181515    0.00434307     -0.0248712   0.226976   -0.0686294  0.437169
 -0.0472136  0.127803   0.458812    0.0119074       0.0391649  -0.0190299  -0.0585371  0.264379
  0.468634   1.16498   -0.00263205  0.192809        0.273537    1.13787    -0.0653081  1.41321 
  0.749655   2.20266    0.0205068   0.420249        0.573358    1.42499     0.441232   1.67574
```

Which `@macroexpand`s to essentially the following loops (plus preparation and bounds checking):

```
begin  
    local k 
    for k = 1:size(μ, 2) 
        begin  
            local n 
            for n = 1:size(x, 1) 
                begin  
                    local s = zero(T) 
                    begin  
                        local j 
                        for j = 1:size(W, 3) 
                            begin  
                                local i 
                                for i = 1:size(x, 2) 
                                    s += (x[n, i] - μ[i, k]) * W[k, i, j] * (x[n, j] - μ[j, k])
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end 
                    r[n, k] = s
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

---

Now, to find something more performant, I compared a couple of variants using [`BenchmarkTools.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl/). You can see the full code and results on my laptop [here](https://gist.github.com/phipsgabler/b99b1be5dd816c8f2374534b1c1b5a83). It shows that the Einsum variant already is in fact better than the original:

```
# Original: 
#   memory estimate:  1017.73 MiB
#   allocs estimate:  3429967
#   median time:      361.982 ms (15.94% GC)

# Einsum: 
#   memory estimate:  2.64 MiB
#   allocs estimate:  76
#   median time:      127.536 ms (0.00% GC)
```

By far the most efficient and least allocating variant is the following, which requires `x = x'` and `W = permutedims(W, [2, 3, 1])` (assuming you can change your representation easily):

```
function test_optimized!(res, x, μ, W)
    z = zero(eltype(x))

    for k = 1:size(μ, 1) 
        for n = 1:size(x, 1)
            res[n, k] = z

            for i = 1:size(W, 1)
                for j = 1:size(W, 2)
                    @inbounds res[n, k] += (x[i, n] - μ[i, k]) * W[i, j, k] * (x[j, n] - μ[j, k])
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

function test_optimized(x, μ, W)
    res = zeros(N, K)
    test_optimized!(res, x, μ, W)
    res
end
```

This brings us down to

```
#   memory estimate:  2.63 MiB
#   allocs estimate:  2
#   median time:      521.215 μs (0.00% GC)
```

It uses a couple of "tricks" that can be found [in the docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/#Access-arrays-in-memory-order,-along-columns-1): filling a preallocated matrix in a separate method, accessing strides in column-major order, and using `@inbounds` (although that only improves things at the order of a microsecond).

---

There is also [`TensorOperations.jl`](https://github.com/Jutho/TensorOperations.jl), which I think does more intelligent things under the hood, but it fail on this:

```
julia> @tensor r[n,k] := (x[n,i] - μ[i,k]) * W[k,i,j] * (x[n,j] - μ[j,k])
ERROR: TensorOperations.IndexError{String}("invalid index specification: (:n, :i) to (:i, :k)")
Stacktrace:
 [1] add_indices(::Tuple{Symbol,Symbol}, ::Tuple{Symbol,Symbol}) at /home/philipp/.julia/v0.6/TensorOperations/src/implementation/indices.jl:22
 [2] + at /home/philipp/.julia/v0.6/TensorOperations/src/indexnotation/sum.jl:40 [inlined]
 [3] -(::TensorOperations.IndexedObject{(:n, :i),:N,Array{Float64,2},Int64}, ::TensorOperations.IndexedObject{(:i, :k),:N,Array{Float64,2},Int64}) at /home/philipp/.julia/v0.6/TensorOperations/src/indexnotation/sum.jl:44
```

I guess that's deliberate and has to do with efficiency, see [this issue](https://github.com/Jutho/TensorOperations.jl/issues/10).

Comment: I didn't know there exists a mathematical formulation for manipulation of tensors! 

Even this seems very interesting (the `Einsum.jl` package) is significantly slower than the code I am already using. Here is the results for, N=9851, K=35 ,D=16

`julia> toc()
elapsed time: 0.637507076 seconds
0.637507076

julia> tic()
0x002d22afc74aa53e

julia> @einsum r[n,k] := (x_matrix[n,i] - mus_matrix[i,k]) * w_matrix[k,i,j] * (x_matrix[n,j] - mus_matrix[j,k])

julia> toc()
elapsed time: 156.100774205 seconds
156.100774205`

Comment: `julia> tic()
0x002d22f79f38006a

julia> res = zeros(N,K);

julia> for i in 1:N
                  for k in 1:K
                      res[i,k] = (x_matrix[i,:]-mus_matrix[:,k])'*
                                  w_matrix[k,:,:]*(x_matrix[i,:]-mus_matrix[:,k])
                  end
              end

julia> toc()
elapsed time: 3.66330257 seconds
3.66330257`

Comment: In both cases, the results are exactly the same, a NxK matrix!

Comment: That's not how you should measure performance. Do not measure performance in global scope. Put the code in a function and call twice `@time your_function(params...)`. Ignore the first timing, the second one is what you are looking for. Please take a look at: https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/#Measure-performance-with-[@time](@ref)-and-pay-attention-to-memory-allocation-1

Comment: @LeonidasSouliotis Or, use `BenchmarkTools.jl`. But yeah, I didn't really take into account efficiency that much. I'll look into it when I'm back from holidays.

Comment: @LeonidasSouliotis So, I benchmarked and optimized a couple of things.